# How to bind an arguments object to a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is there a way to bind an array/arguments object to a function, similar to how .apply allows for calling a function with an array of arguments?

For instance, I am building parts of the underscore library, and I'm trying to run call `.setTimeout` with the function that is passed in, and binding the list of arguments. However, it seems like `.bind` is expecting me to list out every argument individually.

```
_.delay = function(func, wait) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return setTimeout(func.bind(this, args), wait);
};
```

This isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little tricky, but you can `.apply` the `.bind` method. You just need to pass the function you are binding to as the first argument, and the `this` argument as the first index of the array. Then the remaining indexes will be passed as arguments.

### Working Example:

```js
var func = function(a, b, c) {
  console.log(a, b, c);
};
setTimeout(func.bind.apply(func, [this, 1, 2, 3]), 100);
```

You'll have to construct your `args` something like this:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
args.unshift(this);
```

Or something like this:

```
var args = [this].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2));
```

Comment: why do you unsifting `this` from `args`? Actually, Does `this` referenced to `window` in your case?

Comment: @TheReason Unshift prepends the `this` object to the array so it will be the first argent passed to `.bind`. In their case, `this` would likely be the `_` object. Run outside a method call, it would be the global object (`window` in a browser) or `undefined` if in strict mode.

Comment: Ah, it works! This is definitely really tricky, and I can see why the actual underscore library just inserts and anonymous function returning a function with apply. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In ES6:

```
func.bind(thisArg, ...argsArray)
```

which under the covers amounts to the same thing as the `bind.apply` shown in another answer.

However, it seems that with the advent of arrow functions, we are using `bind` less and less. Rather than writing

```
func.bind(0, a, b, c)
```

which forces us to specify a `thisArg` first parameter even if we don't care, we can now write

```
() => func(a, b, c)
```

which is actually shorter. Of course we always have been able to write this as

```
function() { return func(a, b, c); }
```

but that would have been much more verbose.